# What graphics card do I have?

Tags: graphics-card, graphics

Can someone help me identify what graphics card i have without pc

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The FCC logo says MicroStar MS-V328, which is an [MSI nVidia GeForce GTX1060 OC](https://www.blackmoreit.com/ms-v328-msi-ms-v328-armor-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1060-oc-6gb-gddr5-graphics-card.html)